# Parse separate JSON months into a single column

Tags: mysql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working in Snowflake. I have a JSON object with some data elements like square footage, latitude, longitude, etc. The object also features months - month_1, month_2, month_3, etc. Each month is a column and the value is either 1 or 0. What I would like to do is turn those 12 month columns into a single month column. Is there any way to easily do this, other than to just write out a case statement, like:

```
when month_1=1 then 'JAN'
when month_2=1 then 'FEB'
```

I initially tried using UNPIVOT, but it doesn't seem to get me there... I think largely because I'm not concerned with the actual values in those month columns; rather, I am just interested in whether or not that column is true or false.

I tried to UNPIVOT, initially.

```
with

test as (
  

select 
    value['month_1.0'] as January, 
    value['month_2.0'] as February,
    value['month_3.0'] as March,
    value['month_4.0'] as April,
    value['month_5.0'] as May,
    value['month_6.0'] as June,
    value['month_7.0'] as July,
    value['month_8.0'] as August,
    value['month_9.0'] as September,
    value['month_10.0'] as October,
    value['month_11.0'] as November,
    value['month_12.0'] as December

from logs, lateral flatten( input => data ) as d
)

select * 
from test
unpivot (placeholder for month in (
January, 
February,
March,
April,
May,
June,
July,
August,
September,
 October,
 November,
 December))
```

I was hoping it would be 6 rows, which is how much data is in my JSON object - instead, it's 72 rows, because instead of only providing a month name for the month that has a 1 or 0 per row, I'm getting every month.

Comment: can you give us a sample of the json, so we can test any answer we give you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.